# Do touch events work in ionic like this? Get screenX with the Angular framwork

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Is the ionic framework able to use touch events like in js?

Just like this:

```
htmlElement.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
  var t = htmlElement.touches[0];
  var output = t.screenX + " , " + t.screenY;  
},false);   

htmlElement.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
  htmlElement.preventDefault();
  var t = htmlElement.touches[0];
  var output = t.screenX + " , " + t.screenY; 
},false);
```

I need the t.screenX and the t.screenY value in ionic

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's wrong accessing screenX, screenY from just normal angular (click) binding?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nnjrcy

if you bind event using $ in the template:

```
<div (click)="getEvent($event)"></div>
```

In your getEvent method you can access original DOM event object that contains screenX,Y etc

```
getEvent(event) {
    alert(
      "Your screen X: "+ event.screenX +" and Y : "+event.screenY
    )
    console.log(event.screenX)
    console.log(event.screenY)
  }
```

(click) event is handled by hammer.js in Ionic 3, and it should work for both touch and mouse input.

for touch you can also use (tap) binding. Then screenX, screenY should be accessible inside event.srcEvent path

And if you still want to do the binding to low level touch/mouse event on your own ideally you need to leverage "renderer" to ensure your code stays "decoupled" from dom:

```
// check your Angular version to know which Renderer you need to import:
import { Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";

// inject it:
constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
    etc
)

// use ViewChild to bind to DOM element:
@ViewChild('mainSVG') mainSVG: ElementRef;

// do binding in life cycle hook for instance:
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.mainSVG.nativeElement, 'touchstart', this.startInputEvent)
}
```

This looks more complex and for simple projects I guess can be ignored, but in general it is better to let Angular touch dom and deal with it in its own way.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, you can achieve this like so:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('htmlelement');
element[0].addEventListener('click', (e: any) => {
  console.log("clicked");
});
container[0].addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
  console.log("Touchstart");
});
```

However usually a better wat to declare event handlers in ionic is to define it in HTML:

```
 <button (touchstart)="foo($event);">Element 1</button> 
 <button (touchend)="foo($event);">Element 2</button>
```

And then declare a function in component that handles these events

```
foo (event) {
     // Function logic here
}
```

Comment: Would that work like this -> http://www.web.raphael-mittendorfer.com/swipe/